# Error window is not defined when using Forge module

Tags: android, encryption, nativescript, forge

I am new to NativeScript and I am trying to do encryption in the project.
I intended to use the [Forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) module and used `npm install --save node-forge` to install the forge. But once I added import statement (var forge = require("node-forge");
) in the home-page.js file I got this error.***window is not defined***

stack trace:

```
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Successfully transferred bundle.651345b9e00673263e5e.hot-update.js on device emulator-5554.
Successfully transferred vendor.651345b9e00673263e5e.hot-update.js on device emulator-5554.
Successfully transferred 651345b9e00673263e5e.hot-update.json on device emulator-5554.
JS: HMR: Checking for updates to the bundle with hmr hash 651345b9e00673263e5e.
Refreshing application on device emulator-5554...
JS: HMR: Ignored an error while updating module ./home/home-page.js <self-accept-errored>
JS: HMR: ReferenceError: window is not defined
JS: HMR: Cannot apply update with hmr hash 651345b9e00673263e5e.
JS: HMR: window is not defined
Successfully transferred bundle.js on device emulator-5554.
Successfully transferred runtime.js on device emulator-5554.
Successfully transferred vendor.js on device emulator-5554.
Restarting application on device emulator-5554...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.HelloGamma on device emulator-5554.
JS: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.HelloGamma/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Building UI from XML. @app-root.xml:1:1
System.err:  > window is not defined
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.HelloGamma/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Building UI from XML. @app-root.xml:1:1
System.err:  > window is not defined
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Building UI from XML. @app-root.xml:1:1
System.err:  > window is not defined
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1209)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1096)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1083)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1063)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1055)
System.err:     at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:19)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
System.err:     ... 9 more
```

Does anyone know about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may only able to use CommonJS modules in NativeScript. Any Browser / Node specific features will not work within NativeScript environment.

This package uses `window.forge` to keep a global reference, window is indeed a browser specific feature. But since it's used only for storing global reference, a trick is to create global window object before loading this package.

```
global.window = {};
```

But this package also seems to use other browser specific features like loading SWF / ActionScript, those don't have any workaround. You will have to find a native equivalent of same for iOS / Android.

Comment: Thanks, @manoj for the response.I followed [this] (https://www.nativescript.org/blog/how-to-use-any-npm-module-with-nativescript) to be able to use npm packages in nativescript, but it had a lot of issues in nativescript 6 so I left it. I decided to try adding crypto in the native layer.

Comment: As I already said, even if you follow the steps it's not all the modules.